# php artisan migrate No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling ismaster on '10.0.0.106:27017']

Tags: php, laravel-5, server, migrate

I am trying to do

```
php artisan migrate
```

but I got this

```
  No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling ismaster on '10.0.0.106:27017']
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: It seems your mongodb is not reachable.

Comment: how to fix it ?